# Ubuntu nautilus Home's path is /root,how can i change it to /home/username?

Tags: file, ubuntu, nautilus

At first,the file icon was lost in my Ubuntu 20.04.Later i run the `sudo root`，but I still have some trouble in clicking the icon on the desktop to open the files. And now i run the `sudo nautilus`,i see the Home is /root,and when i open terminal in these file,the user is root,i don't know what happened.How can i change the Home to /home/username?and how can i reserve it to be username's terminal by default?

[files images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0g1g.png)
[Terminal images(when open in files)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90bp4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you run `nautilus` with `sudo`, you are running it as the user `root`. This user has it's home directory at `/root`.

Try to run `nautilus` without root, i.e. as a normal user (by simply typing `nautilus`), and your "Home" will be at `/home/username`.
Your "terminal user" will be your normal user account.

Please see the [sudo man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html)

Comment: But in my i couldn't open it just use `nautilus`,what happened with my username's nautilus?

Comment: There is no other response in the terminal,also i could't click the file icon to open files on desktop...

Comment: 1. What happened exactly (any output) if you tried to open `nautilus` from your terminal without `sudo`.
2. What is meant by open files on desktop? You mean e.g. to open a `.txt`-file in a text editor by clicking it inside `nautilus`?

Comment: 1. no any response, i just wait... 2.there used to bulid some files in dektop,and there are some icons i can double click to open them before

Comment: OK,when the `nautilus` running after around twenty minutes... Thank you very much for your reminder.